# Update Object in JSON file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to update the list object in the following file using Powershell:

```
{
"$schema":  "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion":  "1.0.0.0",
"parameters":  {
    "environment":  {
            "value":  ""
        },
    "keyVaultAccessPolicies":  {
        "value":  {
            "list": []
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is my Powershell that I have written so far:

```
$parametersTemplate = "C:\deploy.parameters.json"
$parametersJson = Get-Content $parametersTemplate -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$parametersJson.parameters.keyVaultAccessPolicies.value.list = $armAccessPolicies
$parametersJson | ConvertTo-Json | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | Set-Content $parametersTemplate
```

$armAccessPolices is a json string that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "tenantId":"**************",
    "objectId":"**************",
    "permissions":{"keys":"","secrets":"Get","certificates":"","storage":""}
},
{
    "tenantId":"**************",
    "objectId":"**************",
    "permissions":{"keys":"","secrets":"Get","certificates":"","storage":""}
}
]
```

When the JSON file is updated the result I am getting is this:

```
"keyVaultAccessPolicies":  {
      "value":  "@{list=[...]}"
  }
```

I'd like some advice so the file looks like this:

```
"keyVaultAccessPolicies":  {
      "value":  {
           "list": [...]
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You kind of answer your own question when you say that `$armAccessPolices` is a json string.

You are appending a string to `$parametersJson.parameters.keyVaultAccessPolicies.value.list`.

What you want is to append a list.
To do so, you need to convert `$armAccessPolicies` to a PSObject first and then convert everything back to the final json, like this:

```
$parametersTemplate = "C:\deploy.parameters.json"
$parametersJson = Get-Content $parametersTemplate -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
# See, we are not setting the json string but rather the resulting psobject.
$parametersJson.parameters.keyVaultAccessPolicies.value.list = ($armAccessPolicies | ConvertFrom-Json) 

$parametersJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | Set-Content $parametersTemplate
```

The only meaningful change here was the `.list` assignement which now is set to the psobject representation of `$armAccessPolicies` instead of the raw string through `($armAccessPolicies | ConvertFrom-Json)`

Note: You should also  define the depth to something bigger than 4 (default) to avoid data loss after the 4th layer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Works as expected now. Think I’d been staring at it for too long to see the obvious answer.

Comment: Also, thanks for the advice on the Depth. I was seeing some objects instead of values and increasing the depths has fixed it.

Comment: Is there a way that $armAccessPolicies can always be treated as an array when converted to json? "list" is an array but when $armAccessPolicies.PSobject.BaseObject.Count = 1, "list" is treated as an object so I get a bad json file.

Comment: Worked it out: $armAccessPolicies = [PSCustomObject]@{ list = $armAccessPolicies} and then $parametersJson.parameters.keyVaultAccessPolicies.value = $AccessPoliciesObject (update value instead of list)